# Issue when converting a Xcode project to ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I've got the following warning: "Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released after assignment" for the following snippet of code. Could somebody please help me clear this up? The second line where I set detailViewController.restaurantsSortedByDistance is the portion highlighted by the warning.....

```
**   RestaurantList.h **
    @property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *restaurantsSortedByDistance;

**         end        **

 RestaurantList *detailViewController = [[RestaurantList alloc] initWithNibName:@"RestaurantList" bundle:nil];

        detailViewController.restaurantsSortedByDistance = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self returnRestaurantsSortedByDistance:rows]];
```

Comment: How did you declare restaurantsSortedByDistance? Most likely you want it to be a (retain) property, but instead it's an (assign) property.

Comment: I've run into this issue as well. The conversion tool is doing the correct thing. It's the compiler warning that is in error. The default is actually "strong" under ARC, not "assign". (assign is the default in manual reference counting mode). If you leave your code alone you'll see that it actually works fine as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your **detailViewController**.h set  your **restaurantsSortedByDistance** property to strong.

Comment: yup, that got rid of the warnings. I have 2 questions though. 1) why didn't Xcode automatically add 'strong' in for me if that's what it was looking for to prevent the warning. 2) what is strong? what does it indicate?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: properties in your viewcontrollers are set by you depending on what you need. Strong = the object will keep a reference to the element in a way that as long as the first exist the second will, Weak = The object keeps a reference but cannot keep the element alive, it will point it as long as it exists but not after it doesnt.